# Como posso transformar um arquivo INI em um Dict?

Tags: python, ini

Como posso transformar os dados de um arquivo `.ini` em um `dict` em Python?

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso em `Python`?

```
[database]

host = localhost
password = sabe_nada_de_python
port = 3306
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, usando [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html):

```
import configparser
import os

configuracao = configparser.ConfigParser()
configuracao.read(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "meuarquivo.ini"))
host = configuracao["database"]["host"]
password = configuracao["database"]["password"]
port = configuracao["database"]["port"]
```

Comment: +1. boa resposta. Eu achei que era nativo, mas precisa instalar.